# selectivity applied for angularjs select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to use selectivity applied to select element, which renders his options via angularjs controller. The problem is that the selectivity applies before angular passes the options to the template. For the protocol - the selectivity styling works fine with static options, but they are not data-binded and static options are not a solution at all.

html

```
<select id="roleIds" name="roleIds[]" ng-options="role.name for role in roles track by role.id" ng-model="selected_roles" multiple></select>
```

angularjs

```
$http
({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    isArray: true
}).then
(
    function(response)
    {
        $scope.name = response.data.name;
        $scope.email = response.data.email;
        $scope.roles = response.data.roles;
        $scope.selected_roles = response.data.selected_roles;
        $scope.selected_accesses = response.data.selected_accesses;
        $scope.accesses = response.data.accesses;

        jQuery('#roleIds').selectivity({
          multiple: true,
          tokenSeparators: [' ']
         });
    }
);
```

How can i achieve this? Is it possible to have nice multiselect while handle the data with angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Angular directive and apply selectivity in the directive's link function. You can then add the directive to the html template on the selected element. Since the roles are can be updated and retrieved at a later time, I added a watch to the roles object.

```js
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").controller("SelectivityCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {

  var roles = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "test"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "blah"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "third"
  }];
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.roles = roles;
    $scope.selected_roles = [];
  }, 1000);
});
angular.module("app").directive("jSelectivity", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      jSelectivity: "<"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
      scope.$watch("jSelectivity", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          var test = jQuery(elem).selectivity({
            multiple: true,
            tokenSeparators: [' ']
          });
          $(test).on('change', function(e) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue($('#roleIds').selectivity('data'));
            modelCtrl.$render();
          });
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/stylesheets/selectivity-jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/javascripts/selectivity-jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="SelectivityCtrl">
    <select id="roleIds" name="roleIds[]" ng-options="role.name for role in roles track by role.id" ng-model="selected_roles" multiple j-selectivity="roles"></select>
    <p>{{selected_roles|json}}</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

**Update**:

I added an onChange event handler on the new selectivity div which will allows us to properly update the model data. I would recommend writing a custom  Angular directive that wraps around the functionality of selectivity. This will allow for much more user friendly design and code.

Comment: Well, now the selectivity is applied, but it wiped out all the angularjs directives and the options in the select are not data-binded - it's like static select.

Comment: The code I provided is just an example. You need to keep your code and fetch the roles and other details from your API as you have shown in your code in your post.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what i have done. The select has the correct options selected, but they are not **data-binded** with the controller. When i inspect the select element i see that the angularjs directives such as ' ng-model="selected_roles" ' are wiped out by the selectivity. For example when i deselect one of the options, this does not apply any change in the value of $scope.selected_roles in the controller, so when i submit the form nothing changes in the database. Should i add these directives as attributes in the directive **link** function or something?

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope this will be useful for other people. Can you recommend some tutorials and materials about angularjs directives? I am relatively new to angular and especially about directives, so i want to understand the directives well, as i start to understand that they are very powerful tool in angular.